# how to append data from php for loop into textarea?

Tags: php, html, textarea, append

i have an array that prints some hyperlinks . I wonder how i can print those hyperlink htmls in to textarea. In another word i want to append those hyperlinks html int to text area. Could any one show me how this can be done? Thanks

```
// iterate the new array
for($i = 0; $i < count($foo[1]); $i++)
{    
  $SValue[1]=str_replace('"', '', $foo[1] );
  $SValue[1]=str_replace(' ', '', $SValue[1] );
?>
  <a href="./ok.php?vidID=<?php echo trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $SValue[1][$i])) ; ?>/<?php echo $foo3[1][$i] ; ?>&title=<?php echo trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $SValue2[1][$i])) ; ?>"><?php echo trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $SValue2[1][$i])); ?></a><br/>
<?
}//end of for loop
```

Comment: put the link text into a variable, then `<textarea><?php echo $link_text ?></textarea>`?

Comment: thanks for reply .i tried that but it only prints the last data in array not the rest ! how to print all of them in textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//create variable to hold content
$content = "";
// iterate the new array
for($i = 0; $i < count($foo[1]); $i++)
{    
  $SValue[1]=str_replace('"', '', $foo[1] );
  $SValue[1]=str_replace(' ', '', $SValue[1] );

  $content .= '<a href="./ok.php?vidID= ' . <?php trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $SValue[1][$i])) ; ?> . '/' . <?php $foo3[1][$i]; ?> . '&title=' . <?php trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $SValue2[1][$i])) ; ?> . '">' . <?php trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $SValue2[1][$i])); ?> . '</a><br/>';

}//end of for loop
?>
<textarea><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
```